# Where is Pave and why is Festival not being celebrated?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Today I logged on to animal crossing new horizons. I was expecting Isabelle to were a fun hat, confetti flying around, villagers dancing, and Pave in the plaza. Instead I got nothing. I have the latest version. I bought all the furniture and clothing items. There was even a notice on the bulletin board saying Festival was on the 15. Do I have to wait later in the day or is my game glitched?

Comment: you're not alone, I didnt get it either. Upon starting the game today everything went back to "normal", all the lights and decorations around the town center vanished.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment. There was a bug and starting the game from passive sleep had everyone forget about festivale. To fix it, I closed the game down completely and restarted it.

After doing so, Isabelle was back on the announcements to start the event.

Comment: I restarted my switch and it didn't do anything

Comment: Well there's always next year. From now on when I'm done playing I will always turn my switch off instead of on sleep mode.

Comment: that's unfortunate, but to be honest it was a really bad event... so you didnt miss much :)

Answer (score 0):

this has happened to me but you have to have the upgraded town hall to celebrate festivals.